# change the scope in this function to the invoker with jquery or vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sample code with what I want to do is commented:

```
 myObj.doSomething({
    callbackFn: function( result ) {
      if ( result && result.retval !== null )
      {
        // I want to assign the values on result.retval to myObj
        // but `this` is not equal to myObj.
        // is it correct to just do this?
        myObj.some_val = result.some_val;
      }
    }
  });
```

Normally with underscore, I'd use its `_.bind()` function to do this. The code I'm dealing with doesn't use underscore. What's the best way to do this with vanilla JS or jQuery?

Comment: [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind/)

Comment: Can you change the implementation of `doSomething`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript itself provides [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
myObj.doSomething({
    callbackFn: function( result ) {
      if ( result && result.retval !== null )
      {
        this.some_val = result.some_val;
      }
    }.bind(myObj); // <--
  });
```

This is under the assumption that you cannot change the implementation of `doSomething`. If you can change it, see [@10100111001's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920773/218196).

But you might as well use the code you currently have. I don't see a big benefit of using `.bind` here.

---

Just for fun, a simple version of`.bind` is pretty easy to implement yourself, should you find yourself in an environment that doesn't support it:

```
function bind(f, thisValue) {
    return function() {
      return f.apply(thisValue, arguments);
    };
}

var boundF = bind(f, myObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this where you can `call` the `callbackFn` in `doSomething` with the proper this value.

```js
var myObj = {};
myObj.doSomething = function (obj) {
    obj.callbackFn.call(this, {some_val: "test"});
}

myObj.doSomething({
    callbackFn: function( result ) {
      if ( result && result.retval !== null )
      {
        // I want to assign the values on result.retval to myObj
        // but `this` is not equal to myObj.
        // is it correct to just do this?
        this.some_val = result.some_val;
      }
    }
  });

console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `with` block is  pretty much :

```
  function( result ) {
          if ( result && result.retval !== null )
          {
            with(myObj){
                some_val = result.some_val; // Even,no Need "this" 
            }
           
          }
        }
```

Even, No need `this`

Comment: thanks for info ... anyway, it does not mention which mode : strict, non-strict, .. or else